# Initializing a UserForm and Loading Variables with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, initialization

I have a userform with an initialize event as follows:

```
Public CurrSpanNum, CurrSegNum As Integer
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

        CurrSegNum = Sheets("UserData").Range("C2").value
        Debug.Print "SegForm, SpanNum = " & CurrSpanNum
        CurrSpanNum = Sheets("UserData").Range("D2").value
        Debug.Print "SegForm, SegNum = " & CurrSegNum

End Sub
```

In the immediate window I see:

```
SegForm, SpanNum = 
SegForm, SegNum = 3
```

The value 3 is placed in both cells before the form is initialized. Why can't I seem to load SpanNum while SegNum is able to load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your CurrSpanNum variable is not initialized and so prints nothing, What would you expect?